# Crash while Mapping output to Core data in Restkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, restkit

I have 3 tables userID, profile which has to one relationship and searchId, profile has to one relationship. I set the delete rule to Nullify for both relationship. I have two View Controllers in which i am mapping the json data from server using Restkit.

In View Controller 1: 
   In this view Datas are fetched from Server and Mapped in DB using Restkit. (userID - > profile)

In View Contrller 2:
   Data is retrieved from server and mapped into DB (searchID -> profile).

There is a refresh button in View Controller 1, which will fetch the data from server and map(update) the db.

Problem: After View Controller 1 loads the data from server, I am trying to search the data in View Controller 2 which loads the data from the server. I am Loading those data in ViewController 1 UI (Because View Controller 1 results and View Controller 2 Results are in Similar Format) No Problem here.

But When i Click the refresh button again,  App got Crashed with Following Error. I can't able to figure out the problem.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x8b4b950 <x-coredata://EE00CF63-BECD-40FC-B531-1424930D75D6/USERID/p42>''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2b78022 0x2d28cd6 0x230b506 0x230b0a7 0x230ac86 0x2316db9 0x2316c26 0x231a38e 0x234a5f6 0x2338df7 0x233791e 0x233765d 0x2336f0a 0x1d59d91 0x1d59895 0x1d3f33e 0x231af3f 0x231a449 0x234a5f6 0x2338df7 0x23379ec 0x233765d 0x2336f0a 0x1d59d91 0x1d59895 0x1d3f33e 0x231af3f 0x231a449 0x234a5f6 0x2338df7 0x2338d64 0x1d70d50 0x273ebd 0x274727 0x1d7463e 0x1d6d1e7 0x1d6ceea 0x29c725 0x2a78b0 0x29e0f7 0x29e773 0x29ea5a 0x28ed330 0x28eef0c 0x28eecb4 0x28ee402 0x97dd7b24 0x97dd96fe)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: add breakpoint to the objective-c exceptions. you will see call stack and the line that caused crash

Answer (score 1):

Are all your managed object contexts saved before you hit the refresh button? The "CoreData could not fulfill a fault" error means that Core Data was trying to find a row with a particular ID, but it could not find the row. This can happen when you pass managed objects across threads (which you should never do, you should pass their object IDs) or pass their IDs across threads without saving the context in which the object was created.